# why struct option array needs an addtional dummy entry when using getopt_long

Tags: c, command-line-interface, getopt, getopt-long

For example the option array is:

```
static struct option const long_options[] =
{
  {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
  {"version", no_argument, 0, 'v'},
  {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Is it for padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the man page for [`getopt_long()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getopt_long/):

> ```
> int
>  getopt_long(int argc, char * const *argv, const char *optstring,
>      const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
> ```

The `argc` and `argv` pair show one way to say how many entries there are in an array (by explicit count, though since `argv[argc] == 0`, there is also a sentinel there).  The `optstring` indicates short arguments; the `longindex` is an output parameter.  That leaves only the pointer `longopts` which means that the function must be able to tell how many entries are in the array without any supporting count (there is no `longoptcount` argument), so the end of the array is marked by all values zero - a sentinel value.

Answer (score 3):

It's a 'sentinel' so the code processing the array knows when it's gotten to the end.